# git I can pull correctly but cannot push

Tags: git, assembla

I use git to work with assembla in my Mac.
I can pull from remote branch successfully but cannot push to it.

```
[13:59:36]  $ git pull origin master
From git.assembla.com:something
 * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
Already up-to-date.
[14:00:00]  $ git push origin master
E, [2014-03-17T19:00:14.572139 #4924] ERROR -- : permission denied
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Does anybody know what's wrong with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have read permissions to that repository, but can't write to it.  Contact the repo's owners.

Meanwhile, you can just work on your own fork, as git is a distributed VCS that lets you do neat things like that.

Comment: Thanks. I use the same account in Tortoise-git and git. The one in Tortoise-git works fine, but the one in git cannot push. I think there may be some privilege setting incorrect in git. Where can I set the privilege in git?

Comment: I'm willing to be it has something to do with your rsa keys.  What's the exact URL you used when you `git cloned`?

Comment: git@git.assembla.com:um_iis.git

Comment: what are the *filenames* in ~/.ssh for you?